# Laravel - reading config variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I don't get it - when I search for this problem I get told to do the followng:

`composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear`

And yet it is not making a difference.  In my `.env` file:
`PASS_DOMAIN=domain.local`

In my `/config/app.php` file:
`'pass_domain' => env('PASS_DOMAIN', 'example.com'),`

Yet in my middleware located in `/app/Http/Middleware/` if I place the following:

`dd(config('pass_domain'));`

I get nothing.  Why cant I access this variable?  Originally I had `env('pass_domain')` but nothing is letting me see this damn variable.

Any help?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should be using `config('app.pass_domain')`. Note that the config file is specified as a part of the key.

Comment: config('file.key')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
dd(config('app.pass_domain'));
```

Comment: Yay, thank you.  I didn't know that I had to reference it like that.

Comment: @Chud37 Me neither before using ones and thank you too :)